# Julia: Passing a field of a composite type as argument

Tags: types, julia, composite-types

Consider the following example

```
struct valueStruct
    a::Vector{Float64}
    a2::Vector{Float64} 
end

values = valueStruct(ones(10), ones(10));
values2 = 1:10;

function testFunc!(values, values2)
    values.a .= values.a .* values2;
end
```

I want to create a function `testFunc2!` such that it can take in a `field` instead of the entire object. For example: `testFunc2!(values.a, values2)`. However, I keep getting this error:

`LoadError: LoadError: syntax: "values.a" is not a valid function argument name`.

I want to do this because in my actual code, I want to apply `testFunc!` recursively in a loop on the struct `values`, e.g. `testFunc!(values.a2, values.a)`. I know that I can do soemthing like this:

```
function testFunc!(values, values2, n)
    values.a .= values.a .* values2;
    for i = 1:n
        values.a2 .= values.a;
    end
end
```

However, that's not what I want. In my actual code, I need to have a flexible function such that I can apply it to the fields of a type. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand the problem. This works fine:

```
struct ValueStruct
    a::Vector{Float64}
    a2::Vector{Float64} 
end

function testfunc!(a, b)
    a .*= b
end

values = ValueStruct(ones(10), ones(10))
values2 = 1:10
testfunc!(values.a, values2)
```

BTW: There is a strong convention in Julia that type names should be capitalized: `ValueStruct`, not `valueStruct`. There is also a convention that function names should be all lowercase, though that seems to be less strict.